# Probabilistic Difference between Autoencoders and Variational Autoencoders

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

I have recently read up about Autoencoders and Variational Autoencoders. In Variational Autoencoders, the loss is modeled based on what distribution we choose for P(x|z). So, if we choose it to be Gaussian, we get the reconstruction term as MSE.

The thing that I am struggling with is that we also use MSE in Autoencoders. Now, does this mean that we are also modelling the output of the decoder as Gaussian,and so we get MSE to minimize, or do we take MSE as it is intuitive. (I know we can use BCE as well. Again is this because of how we model the output of the decoder or just because it makes sense).

If so, does this mean that a normal Autoencoder is also somewhat probabilistic. If yes, then what is the difference between VAE and a traditional AE. Is it only that we can restrict the distribution of the latenet space  to our choice in VAE or is there something else as well? or Is it wrong to look at a traditional AE in a probabilistic sense??

I have read up about the probabilistic outlook on an AE in Goodfellow's book (stochastic encoder and decoder), but am still very confused.